# How can I restrict access for users to access PHPMYADMIN pages and have risk to delete all data from databases or theft datas

Tags: php, mysql, networking, phpmyadmin

Today I want to know some information about a little problem i have with my project. In general I have a little project, mini website when I want manage i.e. my ticket for my customer for discounts and spacial sales. The problem is that the site is "hosted" local with xampp for make some updates for site and real host is make with NGROK tool to access website remotely AND sometimes I introduce in header this url (`localhost/phpmyadmin` - for xampp host or `ngroklink/phpmyadmin` for ngrok host) to access databases and keep all data safetly and make my code to work good if code make mistakes.
[image]
Just like in the image that I will attach here in the question, you can see that the host created by xampp is redirected by ngrok. My problem that I want to solve is how I can restrict the access of all users to access the database through that url mentioned above and to have practical access to the databases.
Like the solutions I found is to create an htaccess file where I can restrict access to the database with a username and a password, but if I intentionally made a mistake with the password, I no longer had access to it until I deleted those files . A second method is to create an 'IF' condition in php in the `index.php` file in the `phpmyadmin` from xampp  folder where they will be redirected to a login page where they must enter a username and a password as in a real site. A third method is to do a little networking and to put, for example, the databases on a url address like '`localhost:8585` and for the website to be on `localhost:8080` where the website will be redirected in turn his ngrok remote through his link and specify in database handler file with php that the connection will be made to `localhost:8585` for databases.
At the moment I have tested the first method and the other two not yet, but I want solutions or little help to redirect the unauthorized access of the other users who are not allowed to access the databases. I know that my method is a bit risky because I am subject to an attack, for example, and the server can be affected along with the equipment. I accept any answer regardless of whether it is a help involving php, networking, or files written in other programming languages ​​or even changing the configuration in xampp.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an Alias set up to run phpMyAdmin like this

```
Alias /phpmyadmin5.2.1 "${INSTALL_DIR}/apps/phpmyadmin5.2.1/"

<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/apps/phpmyadmin5.2.1/">
  Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  Require local             
# To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

Make sure it includes this line as below

```
Require local
```

And not

```
Require all  granted
```

This will restrict access to only users on the Server PC

Alternatively, if **you** want to access `phpMyAdmin` remotely, you could add a specific set of IP address's instead

```
Require local
Require ip 111.222.333.444, 111.444.555.666
```

> Apache require documentation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html